# Understanding echo/spawn/send/expect construct

Tags: shell, pipe, expect

Here is a line from a bash script I am trying to understand:

```
echo "spawn myscript.sh arg1 arg2; expect \"Please enter your value: \"; send \"myval\r\"; expect eof" | expect
```

I think I understand the first `expect` and the `send`.

Q1:  Does `expect` work only with `spawn`?

Q2:  What is the purpose of the last expect after the pipe?

Q3:  In general, can you guess what the original author of this line was attempting to accomplish?

Comment: I came here looking for a way to `echo` out of an `expect`-script. `exec echo testbla` works, but produces no output unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q1: The purpose of expect is to automate interactive programs. To launch the program and interact with it, you use the `spawn` command.

Q2: the last expect after the pipe is the expect binary. If not given a file argument, it reads its stdin to get the script to execute.

Q3: The author wanted a mechanism to automatically pass a value when the script  prompts for one. That's it.

I strongly suspect (depending on what myscript.sh does) that you don't need expect at all:

```
echo "myval" | myscript.sh arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 2):

Q1: I'm not an `expect` user, but it seems clear that `spawn` runs a script in the background and makes it controllable by `expect`, rather than just running without any interactivity.

Q2: The string is passed as a script to `expect`. I assume, like most scripting languages, this is equivalent to saving the string to a file and running `expect file`.

Q3: It looks like a test to see that `myscript.sh`, when run, prints a message and responds to a user provided value by exiting without printing anything.

In other words, I expect you should be able to run this script with the same result:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn myscript.sh arg1 arg2 # Run `myscript.sh arg1 arg2` and return control to `expect`
expect "Please enter your value: " # Succeeds if the script prints this value
send "myval\r" # Simulate entering this value
expect eof # Succeeds if the script ends without printing anything
```